# Django session strange behavior

Tags: django, django-sessions

Currently using django 1.7.

I'm using a file based session storage and have request.session.modified set to True. In a simple DB record creation, i store the row id in the session like so:

```
request.session['rid'] = xyz
request.session.modified = True
```

I checked if the value is really in the session and it is. In another request (same session though), I tried to read the 'rid' value but the 'rid' does not reflect the newer value i just created instead it shows the older value.

The browser is kept open and record creation is a constant process.

I also checked the session_key and its the same in both cases. I'm not creating any new session vars apart from this value (or modifying it). I switched to file based session storage because DB session had the same issue.

I'm at loss as to how this is happening. Can somebody help?

TIA

Comment: is session middleware enabled?

Comment: Try this on `settings.py`: `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True`

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo. I did this. I removed django.contrib.sessions and put the above directive but no dice.